# Insert image with javascript on specific page

Tags: javascript

Hi how do I insert a image on a specific page when users visit my site? 
I want to show an image when users visit the url: http://ww.exsample.com/order/cart/

It can be done with java script but how exactly?

Is it as simple as this:

`if(document.URL.indexOf("order/cart/") >= 0){ 
var image = new Image; image.src ="http://www.exsample.com/images/wow.jpg"
}`

Thanks alot

Comment: Did you try it (you have to insert the image somewhere, now you're only creating it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the important step where you actually append the image to the document.

```
var image = new Image;
image.src ="http://www.exsample.com/images/wow.jpg";
// the last step needed:
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Sidenote:
Using `document.URL` is okay, however I prefer `document.location`. In your case you could use `document.location.pathname` which would return only the path `/order/cart/`.

Edit:

To put the image into a div, you simple create an additional div:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("order/cart/") >= 0){

    // create the wrapper div
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    // create the image and set the source
    var image = new Image();
    image.src ="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"

    // append the image to the div
    e.appendChild(image);
    // and finally append the div to the document
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! 
So the correct code would be: 
`if(document.URL.indexOf("order/cart/") >= 0){ 
var image = new Image; image.src ="http://www.exsample.com/images/wow.jpg"
}`

Am I missing anything? 

Also is it possible to place the javascript inside a div? I want to correct the placement of the image ofcause. 

Thanks

Comment: I will edit my answer for your question. Also the code you posted still is missing the `append` step.

Comment: Hi Christoph, I have inserted the whole code into my head section and with <script type="text/javascript">. 
Where in the code do we name the <div> ? 

Right now the image is not showing on my page. Is it because of the "document.Url is used instead of: document.location.pathname ?

Comment: No, it's because in the head section, `document.body` is undefined. Append the script to the body and it should work.

Comment: Oh... I dont have access to the body section. Is there a way to do it only with the head section?

Comment: In that case, wrap you whole code into `window.onload = function(){ /*...*/ }`. This runs the code after your entire document has loaded.

Comment: Awesome! Now its showing the image. Can I define the name of the div? So I can place the div correctly on my page.

Comment: Sure you can! Just have a look at the [definition of Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) and pick the member you need. (Probably `id` I guess).

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thanks alot for the help. 
This is my code:
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
if(document.URL.indexOf("order/cart/") >= 0){

    // create the wrapper div
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.className = "reviewbox";
    // create the image and set the source
    var image = new Image();
    image.src ="http://examplesite.com/Resources/Files/div/review-box.jpg"

    // append the image to the div
    e.appendChild(image);
    // and finally append the div to the document
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}
}

    </script>

Comment: Hi Christoph, not really. The image is showing but its jumping around after which screen size I set so the image is not placed exactly on the correct place. Is it my css coding? 

Here is my css:
.reviewbox{position:relative; margin-top:-900px; margin-left:450px; width:711px;}

Comment: It's most likely the CSS, but I think it's better to ask a new question for that (with more context information) since the initial problem has been solved.